# Codeigniter - Multiple insert_id

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 3 tables for shopping. The one is shopping table for Shopping Cart. Second is orders table. Last one is ordersItem table. (All orders here.) I want to insertid from orders table to ordersItem table multiple. It works but just add one row on ordersItem. I added more product to shopping cart, but when I add insertId, It just add one row and one product to ordersItem table. If I use this without insertId it works correctly.(It adds multiple rows). How I can do this correctly?

Controller:

```
public function insert(){


            $data = array (

                "ordersItem" => json_encode($this->input->post("serviceId")),

                "ordersCus" => $this->session->userdata('people_id'),

                "ordersStatus" => $this->input->post("status"),

                "ordersDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            );

        $this->db->insert("orders", $data);
        $ordersId = $this->db->insert_id();

        $cusId = $this->session->userdata('people_id');

        $checkout = $this->service_model->checkout($cusId);

        foreach ($checkout as $check) {

            $data = array (

                "ordersItemOrdersId" => $ordersId,

                "ordersItemServiceId" => $check->shoppingServiceId,

                "ordersItemEstateId" => $check->shoppingEstateId,

                "ordersItemVehicleId" => $check->shoppingVehicleId,

                "ordersItemPiece" => $check->shoppingPiece,

                "ordersItemAmount" => $check->shoppingPrice,
            );

            $insert = $this->db->insert("ordersItem", $data);

            if($insert) {

                $this->db->where('shoppingCusId', $cusId);
                $this->db->delete('shopping');

                redirect(base_url("checkout"));


            }else {

                echo "Hata!";

            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `redirect(base_url("checkout"));` outside the foreach loop as it will run the loop iteration and then redirect preventing more rows from being added.

Pseudo-code example:

```
foreach ($checkout as $check) {
    ...
}

redirect(...);
```

I would also suggest using transactions:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
foreach ($checkout as $check) {

    $data = array(
        "ordersItemOrdersId" => $ordersId,
        "ordersItemServiceId" => $check->shoppingServiceId,
        "ordersItemEstateId" => $check->shoppingEstateId,
        "ordersItemVehicleId" => $check->shoppingVehicleId,
        "ordersItemPiece" => $check->shoppingPiece,
        "ordersItemAmount" => $check->shoppingPrice,
    );

    $this->db->insert("ordersItem", $data);
}
$this->db->trans_complete();
if ($this->db->trans_status()) {
    $this->db->where('shoppingCusId', $cusId);
    $this->db->delete('shopping');
    redirect(base_url("checkout"));
} else {
    echo "Hata!";
}
```